# Why can't I add my strongest Pokémon to a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

For some reason, I can't add my strongest Pokémon to a friendly gym? Will someone tell me why this is happening for me?

Answer (score 3):

Your Pokémon must have **full HP** (Health Points).

You probably just defeated the gym with your strongest Pokémon and wanted to place it directly in it, but I guess you didn't conquer it without losing HP.